# Tab Bar is not visible with SWRevealviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller, xcode9.2

I am using tab bar with four tab bar item.
First tab bar item view is front view of swrevealviewcontrtoller.
I attached storyboard view controllers detail image.[image]

And output with no tab bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi below i added tabbar and display in viewcontroller.

Step 1:

First Embed the tabbar controller to navigation controller.

Step 2:

Then add the viewcontrollers to the tabbar.

Here i added only one screen navigation controller.
Then i added same swrevealview for side menu. 
If u have any doubt let me know.

[image]

This is output screen :

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much ...I solve problem partially. Added tab bar on view controller but reveal menu button not working.Can I embed navigation bar to tab bar controller? please give me solution for that..

Comment: @VinayakBhor thank for your reply. Tabbar its working fine now?

Comment: Yes.Navigation bar reveal bar item not working ..is it possible to embed navigation controller to tab bar Controller

Comment: Its possible, here also i did like that only. First screen embed with navigation controller, then i connected SwRevealview controller. Check that image.

Comment: I have doubt .In above image Is initial view is swreveal view controller which is connected to tab bar controller?

Comment: Ya, initial view swreveal view controller, one i connected to sidmenu viewcontroller. another one in tabbar controller. But, there first tab bar is home screen. Check it .